# ¿Como imprimir 25 líneas de una lectura de un archivo de texto en c++?

Tags: c++

con una consulta. Que algoritmo o que función podría utilizar, a la hora de que quiera leer un archivo de texto y que en pantalla solo me muestre 25 líneas de texto y que cuando presione enter se muestre otras 25 líneas y así hasta que termine el fichero .

Comment: Busca en Internet cómo leer líneas de texto de un archivo y, también, cómo funciona el bucle `for`. Con eso tendrás el ejercicio prácticamente hecho

Comment: [Usa bucles](https://a.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como digo en el comentario, usa bucles.

```
constexpr int limite = 25;

for (std::ifstream fstream{"archivo.txt"}; fstream;)
{
    std::string linea;
    int indice = 0;
    for (; std::getline(fstream, linea) && indice != limite; ++indice)
        std::cout << linea << '\n';
    std::cout << "Se han leido " << (limite - (limite - indice)) << " lineas\n\n";
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDRaoNAEHz2vmJrIVHSlKaQl5zJT/RVKHJezILuyXmGQPDb7d6ppKTQF09mZ2ZnVrXtVtUFVeP4iqTqvtSQoemc1UVzEg/s/BdiBKk6CXE1WILisf0urLrg1SSpuIsIz5B0rjwczKyG@b3HM@/d3Vw8pCKKzsZCguQA4Qgfkp@XI@x2ewmbDXpCtHhkGQ/5s85pLcUghFc1BdK09CmHFAwZ6py@tRY8tcYGneYtn3s/DItDSvw/pVxwyXF4URRE0xHYlHQhGQwVqESlQ4@lmYTArrTzzGR2ept0KaxWi4hbTwFD8YCF9kGuTO989aB63OBpGn9puBQEtcbSQOyhZC69/fU3m6dBMll2OeUUsyFfNbLa9ZZ8h2EcfwA)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Para esto puedes usar un contador para las lineas

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream my_file("example.txt");
    const int NUM_GET_LINES = 25;
    int count = 0;

    //Open file
    if (my_file.is_open())
    {
        //Read FILE 
        while (getline(my_file, line))
        {
            //If no read all lines
            if (count < NUM_GET_LINES)
            {
                //Print line
                std::cout << line << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                //Wait the input User
                std::cin.get();

                //Reset count
                count = 0;
            }

            //Increment count
            count++;
        }

        //Close the file
        my_file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

    return 0;
}
```